# Cannot get js file to execute from html with Flask in PyCharm

Tags: javascript, html, flask, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to get a html page to run a js script from the static files of the host using Flask (as it's a test project it's a localhost) and for some reason every script comes back as a 404 - I'm using this file structure

```
¬static
  ¬html
    ¬user.html
  ¬js
    ¬script.js
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIXzr.png

I've followed as many guides and other queries on fixing this but I don't get what else I'm missing. I've used `<script src="js/script.js"></script>` to call it, I've used `src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/script.js') }}"` in place of `src="js/script.js`, I've tried using just `script.js` instead of `js/script.js`, I've tried putting it in different places in the file tree and using as many ways as I can think of to call it from these places, I've downloaded plugins, I looked at official sites explaining how to create html and js and etcetera...  Can't get anything to work

EDIT - solved, for some reason clearing my cache for the 2000th time fixed it. Copied the project to another device, same problem, fixed it by replacing `js/script.js` with `static/js/script.js`. That doesn't seem like that's how it should be but it works I guess

Comment: May be use src = "../js/script.js".

Answer (score 0):

Static content in Flask loaded as follows:

```
   <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/script.js') }}"></script>
```

But in this case your html-template should be located in separate folder:

```
static
--js
    scripts.js
templates
  user.html
```

Folder `templates` is the default place where all html-templates are located in Flask.

Comment: didn't work. I got ```127.0.0.1 - - [10/May/2020 12:06:53] "GET /userpage HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [10/May/2020 12:06:53] "GET /js/script.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -``` responses

Comment: How your test.py file looks?

Comment: I believe the relevant area of code is here:   `@app.route('/userpage')
def user_page():
    return app.send_static_file('templates/users.html')`

Comment: `return render_template('users.html')`

Comment: that returns a `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: users.html` when I go to the page

Comment: Try to do your test project according this tutorial https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world  It's a good starting point to learn Flask.